# Thread and Invoke, how to modify a label?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I work on an application in c# and I have a problem with my thread and my UI...

I want to add +1 on my label when the thread is running. The problem is I don't know how I can fix that... I have read a lot of "how to" but the solutions donc work with my app..

My thread class:

```
 class clsWorker
    {
        //Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadLoop));

        public SerialPort port;
        public String url;
        Thread t;
        clsSMS clsobjSMS = new clsSMS();
        SMSapplication clsobjAPP = new SMSapplication();

        public clsWorker(SerialPort serialPort, String urlChamp)
        {
            this.port = serialPort;
            this.url = urlChamp;
        }


        public void StartThread()
        {   
            t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadLoop));
            t.Start();
        }


        public void ThreadLoop()
        {
             // How I can add +1 on the countSMSok label ??
             clsobjAPP.updateCountSMS("countSMSok");

        }
    }
```

My application class :

```
public partial class SMSapplication : Form
    {
public void updateCountSMS(String label)
    {
        int num;

            this.countSMSnok = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.countSMSok = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

            this.Controls.Add(this.countSMSnok );
            this.Controls.Add(this.countSMSok );


         if (label == this.countSMSok.Name.ToString())
        {
           if (int.TryParse(this.countSMSok.Text.ToString(), out num))
                this.countSMSok.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.countSMSok.Text = num++.ToString()));

        }
        else if (label == this.countSMSnok.Name.ToString())
        {
            if (int.TryParse(this.countSMSnok.Text.ToString(), out num))
                this.countSMSnok.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.countSMSnok.Text = num++.ToString()));
        }  
    }

       private void btnRequestStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnRequestStart.Enabled = false;
        this.btnRequestStop.Enabled = true;
        objclsWorker = new clsWorker(this.port, this.urlChecker.Text);
        objclsWorker.StartThread();
    }

}
```

Thanks you very very much for your helping !

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please post any error messages/exceptions you get.

Comment: I have added the exception :) Thanks you for your helping !

Comment: Try adding `IntPtr tempHandle = this.Handle;` before the Invoke call. This accesses the window handle the exception complains about.

Comment: After adding 'IntPtr tempHandle = this.Handle;' before the Invoke call, a new error appear:   The embedded statement can not be a statement or a labeled statement

Comment: Where are you call `StartThread`? Show code.

Comment: Have you tried using Dispatcher (e.g.: Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke)

Comment: I have added the StartThread() call. 
Sorry jacod, I'am a "nweebie" in C#... I don't know.. :)

Comment: Have you added the `this.countSMSok` to forms control collection?

Comment: It appears from the exception that the Controls `countSMSnok` and `countSMSok` have not been initialized.

Comment: Yes I have added the this.countSMSok in the control collection. If I do this.countSMSok.Text = "hello" in the private void btnRequestStart_Click that's work ! But when I call directly the updateCountSMS(String label) method that's fail...

Comment: Possible duplicate, have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c ?

Comment: Make sure, you have any other call of `updateCountSMS` before `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Nice jordanhill123 ! Now the application don't bug, but my label are not actualized... Si the edit please :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create an instance of the label and add the label to the Controls

```
    this.countSMSnok = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.countSMSok = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

    this.Controls.Add(this.countSMSnok );
    this.Controls.Add(this.countSMSok );
```

Comment: Nice jordanhill123 ! Now the application don't bug, but my label are not actualized... Si the edit please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialize new object of `SMSapplication` class, update it and expect it to update your first form. Those are different 'things'.
Also You should use `SynchronizationContext` instead of `invoke`.

Here's working code:

Form:

```
public partial class SMSapplication : Form
{
    private SynchronizationContext context = null;
    private SerialPort port;

    public SMSapplication()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.countSMSok.Text = "0";
        this.context = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    public void updateCountSMS(String label)
    {
        this.context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(updateCountSMSSync), label);
    }

    private void updateCountSMSSync(object o)
    {
        string label = o as string;
        int num;

        if (label == this.countSMSok.Name.ToString())
        {
            if (int.TryParse(this.countSMSok.Text.ToString(), out num))
            {
                this.countSMSok.Text = (++num).ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnRequestStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clsWorker objclsWorker = new clsWorker(this, this.port, this.urlChecker.Text);
        objclsWorker.StartThread();
    }
}
```

And worker:

```
class clsWorker
{
    public SerialPort port;
    public String url;
    SMSapplication clsobjAPP = null;

    public clsWorker(SMSapplication app, SerialPort serialPort, String urlChamp)
    {
        this.clsobjAPP = app;
        this.port = serialPort;
        this.url = urlChamp;
    }

    public void StartThread()
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadLoop)).Start();
    }


    public void ThreadLoop()
    {
        clsobjAPP.updateCountSMS("countSMSok");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hooooo my good, you are a good ! That's work perfectly! I have understand my stupidity. I created an new instanciation... Thanks to you, I will sleep less stupid :) !! Thanks you +++